# Gwt Developer Plugin Issue

Tags: java, google-chrome, gwt

When i click on link created in development mode in eclipse, in chrome browser it shows message to install gwt plugin though I have installed the plugin.

I tried uninstalling chrome browser and reinstalling the plugin.

Any help? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The plugin uses the NPAPI, which is no longer supported by chrome.

You have to options:
get an older version of chrome which supports NPAPI or switch to Super Dev Mode.

I would advice you to use Super Dev Mode, because this is the future.
Take a look here: [GWT Super Deve Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html)

Comment: Actually the issue was with Chrome Version. I was having latest version of chrome  so i switched to lower version it worked.